# Mixing detail rows in the middle of grouped rows

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that need to show rows grouped by some criteria, let's say `SubjectId`.

But, final report preview need to looks like table below:
[image]

Little explanation:

Rows 11 and 12 belongs to group 1, and I need to put those 'Details rows' in the middle of table and after those two columns, I need to continue with group data, and that method would be valid for any group in table.

Everything would be easy if those two details columns are last two columns, but I have problem to get preview from picture if those columns are in the middle.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do this.

You could get something similar by just adding your Gender column at the end and then setting the HideDuplicates property of the textbox top True but that will not allow centering etc.

This was the output I got after applying the above.
[image]

I've used Category twice just as an illustration (that it belongs inside the row group)